# Emacs TRAMP - find-file can't enter user

Tags: emacs, ampersand, plink, tramp

I've recently upgrading to emacs 24.5 with TRAMP 2.2.12.

I use plink to access files on a remote server and am having trouble using the ampersand syntax shortcut to enter a different user than my default.

**Problem**

Executing:

```
'C-x C-f' /user@server:
```

After entering '@', I get the error:

```
"Opening directory: no such file or directory d:/user@".
```

It appears that find-file ignores that I am trying to send this input to plink. All works fine without specifying the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `ido-mode`? If so, then it's a bug I've previously reported.

Comment: I sure am. Didn't see any related bug reports on it but didn't think of the link to `ido-mode`. Are you using a workaround other than disabling it?

Comment: Yes, when I need to use a username I hit `C-f` again to go back to the old-style filename input. Once I've opened one file from that host this isn't necessary. Also, I've set up PuTTY so that it already knows the correct username to use for all hosts that I use regularly. The real pain was training myself not to enter the username; a previous bug meant that TRAMP didn't work correctly in most cases unless I entered it.